# What is web-resource-name in web.xml?

Tags: web.xml

The following are the tags I am using in my web.xml file.

What is `web-resource-name`?

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [a page in the Java EE 6 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjjcd/index.html) which seems to answer your question, and explains some other tags beside:

> A web resource collection consists of the following subelements:
>
> - `web-resource-name` is the name you use for this resource. Its use is optional.